# Trace Norm Inequality for the Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I am having some trouble proving an inequality involving the trace norm or the operator $f{\cal{F}}_Ng$ where $f, g$ are diagonal matrices, f is positive semidefinite and $\cal{F}_N$ is the Discrete Fourier transform matrix given by 
$$
({\cal{F}_N})_{n,m}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{N}nm}
$$
a unitary Vandermonde matrix.
The inequality I am trying to show is this:
$$
\|f{\cal{F}_N} g{\cal{F}_{N}}^{\ast}\|_{tr}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \|f\|_{tr}\|g\|_{tr}
$$
where $(\cdot)^{\ast}$ denotes the Hermitian adjoint.

Has anybody got an idea? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Why do you think the inequality is true?

Comment: I tried to find a counterexample to this, but none has emerged so far. Obviously the counterexamples I was trying to construct are not trivial, i.e. I am not plugging in numbers. :)

Comment: Maybe rewrite $fFg$ using the Schur product and then using inequalities for matrix norms involving Schur products helps.

Comment: I have tried writing $f{\cal{F}}g$ component-wise, the fact is that I don't know an inequality for the trace norm that could help me in this case, because the above matrix is not Hermitian. I have rewritten this in many different ways, even tried to use Hadamard's three line theorem on some function of the form $H(z)=Tr(A^{f(z)})$ where A is the matrix above rewritten in different ways and $f$ is some kind of polynomial in $z, Re(z)\in \left[0,1\right]$, but this has not helped.

Comment: You probably want to use the fact that the trace norm $||.||_{tr}$ is a unitarily invariant norm.  So, for instance, $|| \mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{N}} g \mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{N}}^*||_{tr} = ||g||_{tr}$.

Comment: That unfortunately would not give me the factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ at the front! :) 
Also, by doing that I wouldn't have a sharp bound on $\|\cdot\|_{tr}$, which is the main aim of this. 
The only thing I could do for sure is reducing this to $\|f{\cal{F}}_{N}g\|$.
Thanks for your help anyway! :)

Comment: Erm... Once $f$ and $g$ are diagonal (so the trace norm for them is just the sum of absolute values of the diagonal entries), isn't it true that it suffices to check the inequality just for two single coordinate projections, where it is obvious? Am I missing something subtle?

Comment: What do you mean by "check the inequality for two coordinate projections, where it is obvious"? I am slightly confused :)

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are diagonal matrices with a single $1$ on the diagonal (all other entries are $0$)

Comment: Yes, thank you! You gave me a brilliant idea to prove this inequality in two steps, by considering matrices like the ones you mentioned! Thanks for your great suggestion! Very neat and very clever, as usual for any nice bits of mathematics! :)